# Javascript executing twice after clicking the back button instantclick.io

Tags: javascript, jquery, instantclick.io

I am using the instantclick.io js library, to make my webpage snappier, however when i go back a page, using the back button, every js event that i use (jquery) gets executed twice. I do utilize the 'data-no-instant' attr in my script tag and I do use `InstantClick.on('change', function() {
});`

Example jquery event that gets executed twice:

```
$('.nav .menu-toggle').click(function() {

    ...

});
```

Comment: Which script tag are you adding the `data-no-instant` to? Does it include the script tag that loads the jquery code above?

Comment: Yes it includes, I tried removing it from that script tag too, still no success